# New York Times Api - problem with fetching url of image

Tags: api, react-native

I want to fetch image url and it's problem with "media-metadata", Simulator shows : 'Can't find variable media-metadata'. Title and link work.

```
  componentDidMount() {
axios
  .get(

'https://api.nytimes.com/svc/mostpopular/v2/shared/1/facebook.json? 
      api-key=xxxxx'
  )
   .then(res => {
    const posts = res.data.results;
    this.setState({ posts });
    console.log(posts);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("No Connection");
  });
}
render() {
let displayPosts;
const { posts } = this.state;
displayPosts = (
  <View>
    {posts.map((item, i) => (
      <Element
        title={item.title}
        key={i}
        link = {item.url}
        imageUrl={item.media.media-metadata[i].url }
      />
    ))}
  </View>
);
```

'

Comment: `media` is an array: https://developer.nytimes.com/docs/most-popular-product/1/routes/shared/%7Bperiod%7D/%7Bshare_type%7D.json/get Each item will have multiple `media` elements, so you'll have to either pick one (e.g. `item.media[0].media-metadata[i].url`) or aggregate them somehow.

Comment: 'Can't find variable media-metadata' is still shown

Answer (score 1):

The dash "-" is the reason for the function to throw an error, because it's meant to be a substraction rather than a correct term for an object call. If you use brackets it should work. Try:

```
imageUrl={item.media[0]['media-metadata'][0]['url']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
imageUrl={item.media.media-metadata[0].url }
```

Make i to 0

Comment: 'Can't find variable media-metadata' is still shown

Comment: So you have to make sure item.media has value.

Answer (score 0):

Just dealt with this problem myself, turns out not all of the items in the object will have images, so check for that, then this should work:

```js
function NewsListItem({
  id,
  title,
  media: images,
  published_date: date,
  byline: authors,
  title: headline,
}) {
  return (
    <Link to={`/details/${headline}`}>
      <div className="news-item container">
        {images.length > 0 ? (
          <img
            className="news-item__image"
            src={images[0]["media-metadata"][0]["url"]}
          />
          
          ...
```